# Is there a way of accessing a locked ipod using winfsp for windows 7... map a drive to ipod root?

Tags: windows-7, ipod, fuse

My son cannot remember his password but has tons of pictures.  I was hoping to use something similiar to FUSE on a Windows 7 PC to access the file system without a password.

I have no clue what I'm talking about.  Totally winging this! :/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The tools you pointed to are for accessing a file system. They are not used to crack or defeat a login password. So these will not work for you.

You can try the Apple store, but most likely they cannot help and you may then have to restore the iPad to factory specs. If this can be done (I am not certain about that) Apple would have to help.

Comment: Well, you would know and I've given up.  One thing that this winfsp allowed was to let me try a million passwords.  I tried to map a network drive letter to his ipod \\sshfs\ Ipod-name\internal storage\ -o password_stdout  and it asked for a password to access the file system.  I could enter as many as I wanted without it getting disabled.  So there's that.  But I couldn't guess.  Thanks anyways!